# JQuery Mobile UI DatePicker - Events

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am trying out the JQuery Mobile UI Date Picker ... [Details Here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/ui-datepicker/)

Does anyone know if it's possible to change it's cells colours.

What I want to do is to hardcode some events and add a different color to the dates that have an event.

Has anyone had any experience playing around with this UI Datepicker please?

Thanks

Comment: Look into theming the DatePicker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found this one to be much more robust. https://github.com/jtsage/jquery-mobile-datebox

Check out the demo at http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/